# LNK1104 cannot open file boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib

Tags: c++, boost, msvc-2017

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017, Version 15.9.25

```
Visual C++ 2017 - 00369-60000-00001-AA984
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017 - 15.9.04012.0
ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services - 15.8.31590
ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017 - 5.2.61435.0
```

When I compile the project I'm getting:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-1_61.lib'
```

I've searched all the files in the Project folder and I can see no reference to this file, I am using Boost 1.61 and all I can see in the boost folder is:

```
c:\boost\boost_1_61_0\stage\lib\boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_61.lib
```

How do I change the project settings to get it to use the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the project properties, right click Project in Solution Explorer
2. From the **Configuration Properties** click on the **Platform Toolset** and change the setting to **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**
3. Click on the **OK** button.
4. Clean project and rebuild.

Comment: I would instead of downgrading the compiler simply rebuild/get Boost for vc140. And while at it, upgrade both to vc141.

Comment: @rustyx, unfortunately that's the version I have to use and I cannot just upgrade.